# How to find elements with two specific texts in python webdriver

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, element, siblings

I want to find an element on a website, which has two titles.
E.g. find model x with color x.
Model x is an own element and color x is an own element, but both are in the same class element.
I tried finding the right class by looking for siblings, but I did not succeed.
I can also only look for the link text.

Comment: can you post a link of the website you're working with?

Comment: At first I saw it on Supreme. They use one header for the model and one header for color directly below.

<article><div class="inner-article">
<a style="height:150px;" href="/shop/pants/yfg9ndcs0/rm2keow4x">
<img width="150" height="150" src="//assets.supremenewyork.com/188085/vi/4WH23W6Zizc.jpg" alt="4wh23w6zizc">
<div class="sold_out_tag">sold out</div>
</a>
<h1>
       <a class="name-link" href="/shop/pants/yfg9ndcs0/rm2keow4x">Pleated Trouser</a>
</h1>
<p>
      <a class="name-link" href="/shop/pants/yfg9ndcs0/rm2keow4x">Black</a></p></div>
</article>